# setof with compound predicate

Tags: prolog, prolog-setof

I am struggling with a question in an assignment with prolog.

So, I have the following fact database in prolog:

```
student(name(doe, [john]), 33332, ['CSI1120'] ).
student(name(doe, [jane]), 33336, ['CSI1120'] ).

evaluation('CSI1120', homework(1), ['Prolog', database ], 5).

mark('CSI1120', 33332, homework(1), 3.5 ).
mark('CSI1120', 33336, homework(1), 4.0 ).
```

My goal here is to create a predicate `listAllMarks/3` such as

```
?- returnAllMarks('CSI1120',homework(1),L).
```

Returns:

```
L= [(33332, 3.5), (33336, 4.0)].
```

In order to resolve this problem, I was thinking of making use of the prolog `setof/3`, so I came with the following predicate.

```
returnAllMarks(C,H,L):- setof(L,mark(C,_,H,X),[L|X]).
```

This doesn't seems to work, the predicate always return false. I"m suspecting that this may be due to the fact I am using setof against a compound predicate, but I could be wrong (I'm still in the early stages of learning prolog).

Do you guys have an idea? I look at this problem from all angles, and I am stuck here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write something like:

```
returnAllMarks(C,H,L):- setof( (X,Y), mark(C,X,H,Y), L).
```

Example:

```
?- returnAllMarks('CSI1120',homework(1),L).
L = [ (33332, 3.5), (33336, 4.0)].
```